# How do I use C Library with Rails + Swig?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, swig, spotify

I've programmed 2 rails apps so far that have definitely gotten me pretty comfortable with ruby + rails. I can't say the same about C though. I don't even know what I'm looking at to be honest any time I look at C. It looks like macaroni.

I'm trying to build a spotify web app. The web API sucks, so I have to use this: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/

Documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/

Someone told me I can look at SWIG as a wrapper to communicate with rails.

The data I'm trying to get is 3 things: Number of subscribers, playlist thumbnail, number of tracks... given a playlist URL in the format of: `http://open.spotify.com/user/{{username}}/playlist/{{playlist_id}}`

To be honest, I have no idea where to even start. I can't find any swig tutorials online, and staring at this documentation isn't helping.

Could someone maybe give me a very brief 1,2,3 step procedure that one might go through to do something like this? I don't really expect any code.. but.. this is very roughly what I understand so far.. perhaps someone could help me fill this in..

1. save all C files you need to rails lib directory
2. compile files with ... ?
3. use swig somehow
4. :|

Any help would be super appreciated. I realize this is vague and 'subjective' but I don't even know how to ask this objectively. Just a quick 1-2-3-4-5 to get me started so I can do some googling would be fantastic.

Edit: I did find this, but this seems to be much obsolete: https://github.com/sarnesjo/greenstripes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I have found this. I think this is the answer for my ruby libspotify wrapper: https://github.com/Burgestrand/Hallon

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is certainly not the answer but just thought to gather some related links here.

- http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/Ruby_C_Extension_API_Documentation_(Ruby_1.8)
- http://java.ociweb.com/mark/programming/Ruby_C_Extensions.pdf
- http://people.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/ruby-extensions/ruby-extensions.html

Let us know about any update.